# Is there a function in PHP that will remove empty cells from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

After merging several arrays I run into the issue of having undeclared cells in an array. For example:

`Array ( [0] => 713 [1] => 714 [4] => 712 [6] => 428 [7] => 711 [8] => 515 [9] => 645 )`

I have written a function to rewrite the array without the missing indexes but I was wondering if there is already a built-in function that does this?

Comment: @amosrivera: He means that there are gaps between key identifiers, like 0, 1, 4, 6, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

You can recreate the array using `array_values` and the keys will be "fresh."

Notes

- This will remove all previous keys and replace them with the zero-based set of integers.

Comment: Hah, tried to answer that, got a 'Sorry, this is a duplicate of...'. Character for character the same, +1.

Comment: @Wrikken: Ha. I had to go through a Captcha, which is weird, since this is my first post in hours.

Comment: You need to be carefull with this method as it removes all "keys" from the array so `"red" => "blue"` becomes `[0] => "blue"`. As the array in the question actually doesn't use keys it should work. Just a heads up for other people finding this answer.

Comment: @dragon112: Very true. I'll add that in my post since that is extremely important.

Comment: @dragon112: as the question is explicitly about altering the keys, I think we're safe....

Comment: @Wrikken: I know, but better safe than sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to merge array? If you use `array_merge()` ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php ), numeric keys will automatically be renumbered.